# Spring @ConditionalOnProperty - how to make it work

Tags: spring-boot

I have this component- class and if the property **accounting.generalServiceConfig.accountPageSize** is in application.properties than a log entry should be written into the log file. 
But with this class at bottom it does not work. 
If I add the annotation **@Bean** at method **printAccountPageSize** and return e.g. new Object() than it works.
Is there a possibility to make it work with the class like it is alt the bottom?

```
@Component
public class ConditionalPropertyChecker extends AbstractService {

    protected final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

    public ConditionalPropertyChecker() {
    }

    @ConditionalOnProperty(name = "accounting.generalServiceConfig.accountPageSize")
    public void printAccountPageSize() {
        logger
            .info("the accountPageSize is set in application.properties");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@ConditionalOnProperty is for @Configuration classes producing @Bean.

You can do this:

```
@Component
public class ConditionalPropertyChecker extends AbstractService {

    protected final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

    public ConditionalPropertyChecker(@Value("${accounting.generalServiceConfig.accountPageSize}") Integer pageSize) {
      if (pageSize) {
        logger.info("the accountPageSize is set in application.properties");
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not only for configuration classes. It's perfectly fine to annotate your `@Component` class with `@ConditionalOnProperty`.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I have totally different properties filename, it seems like **@ConditionalOnProperty can only read properties in the application.properties or application.yml**. I tried to add annotation like @PropetySource, still not working.

**Once I add** for example **application.properties** in my project, my class (not only bean, but also component, service, etc) can **conditionally be initialized perfectly**.
However,I don't want to add a new properties file (i.e. application.properties) in the project only because of this annotation. If someone has a more decent solution, please comment below:) Otherwise, I have to create the object manually.

Comment: update: i can extend Condition interface, and then in the implementation, read the property from the project specified property files instead of application.properties.